# react) after deploy using github pages, there are nothing on the page

Tags: reactjs, deployment

[before deploy, on the localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeLgF.jpg)

[after deploy, on the github pages: https://joo168.github.io/goal_tracker/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GusJ.jpg)

it's react.
before deploy, on the localhost, it works.
but after deploy using github pages, there are nothing on the page..
as you can see, *NOTHING*
why did it happen?

Comment: Welcome to SO! We can help you better if you include more information, such as  [Minimal Reproducible Code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), or for this question, the configuration you are using (including your `package.json` would help). Please edit your question to include such information.

Answer (score 0):

i did
yarn build
yarn run deploy

[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oawuE.png)